# Suddenly my resolution of screen changed and i can't reset it

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, nvidia, graphics, xrandr

When i update my OS, suddenly the resolution set's 1024 x 768, i do everything to change it back to 1920 x 1080 but nothing helps me, maybe someone know how can i solve this problem?

In terminal `screenfetch`

``````
                          ./+o+-       levon@levon-desktop
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 47m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2000
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.20
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1024x768
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: GNOME Shell
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i7-7700 @ 8x 4.2GHz [36.0°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: EFI
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 1793MiB / 15977MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

In terminal `xrandr`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
  1920x1200_60.00 (0x2c1) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x2c2) 193.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2056 end 2256 total 2592 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1245           clock  59.88Hz
  1920x1080R (0x2c3) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
```

In terminal `xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920_1080_60.00`

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI1"
```

In terminal `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

In the image below i show that i use `nvidia-driver-440`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080R` ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, again doesn't work

Comment: GPU: EFI <--- looks like nvidia driver compatibility problem

Comment: @A.B maybe, but i think the problem is in `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default`.

Comment: @Levon EFI GPU driver is the minimal driver, like would be VESA before UEFI. No surprise xrandr complains on a feature that is not available

Comment: @A.B, how can i fix it?

Comment: No real idea, I'm avoiding nvidia to avoid having this kind of trouble. But you could check the output of `dmesg` about nvidia module errors (don't dump *all* of dmesg, it's big) and add some parts in your question. Then maybe somebody with nvidia experience can help you. You could also try changing the version of nvidia driver you're using. Of course a probable reboot is needed between tries.

Comment: Forgot to check the Xorg logs (probably `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`)

Comment: @A.B ok, i will change drivers and reboot the system, and send a report to NVIDIA

Comment: Not to NVidia: to Ubuntu. But be sure you can reproduce it with details. Don't send this too fast or it won't be useful. Perhaps you just needed a reboot etc.

Comment: @A.B okay, i will, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104506/discussion-between-a-b-and-levon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and ,this was my configuration.
[image]

so went to nvidia site (https://www.nvidia.in/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-in) and downloaded latest driver and manually installed it

[image]

and after a reboot my issue seems to be solved.

Answer (score 7):

got this issue on Ubuntu 20.04, got it fixed:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

Comment: These commands really saved me from my issue.Actually my issues was suddenly out of nowhwhere , my computer resolution was 4:9 something like that , i tried installing multiple commands and no-effect , but these helped me.

Comment: This is the equivalent of opening "Software & Updates" application and installing the Nvidia driver in the "Additional Drivers" tab

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way to solve this problem ( based on best of my knowledge ),

This update has a bug in it, at the dpkg package ,
To check this try a sudo apt upgrade command, if it returns a error and prompt you that a problem with dpkg then you have to re-calibrate it, use sudo dpkg ––configure –a to do that and restart..
still not fix then you have to remove the last update with the command sudo apt autoremove

Comment: I have already reinstalled Ubuntu :), btw thanks a lot )

Comment: I had the same issue once. It's because the update has a bug init you (A bug in graphics driver) so you just have to run sudo apt-get autoremove to revert to the previous working stage and try to update after a little while (After the bug fix).It work for me and I'm sure its also work for you.